# Angular - Using custom directive to load several components is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, dynamic, components, directive

I am developing an app and for now, I have a dynamic grid generator which divides the space in the screen to fit several components dynamically. So, the component encharged of this must render the components after angular has rendered the page. In order to achieve that I've followed the angular dynamic component loader guide (https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader).

So I am in a point where I do have the component where the other components must be rendered, I have my custom directive to render the components.

*The directive*

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[componentLoader]'
})
export class ComponentLoaderDirective {
    constructor ( 
        public ViewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef 
    ) {}
}
```

Now the component ( grid component )
**grid.component.ts**

```
// ... Stuff above
export class GridComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() public items: gridItem[] = [];
  @ViewChild(ComponentLoaderDirective) componentLoader: ComponentLoaderDirective | undefined;


  constructor(
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver 
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void { this.processRow(this.items) }

  processRow( row: gridItem[] ) { 
    // Some grid related stuff ... 
    for ( let item of row ) { 
      // Stuff performed over every item in each grid row
      
      this.renderComponentIfNeeded(item)
    }
  }

  renderComponentIfNeeded( item: gridItem ):void {
    if ( item.components ) {
      let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
      let viewContainerRef = this.componentLoader.ViewContainerRef;
      viewContainerRef.clear();
      let componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent<any>(componentFactory);
      componentRef.instance.data = item;

      console.log('Directive ', this.componentLoader, 'ComponentRef: ', componentRef);
    }
  }
```

And the HTML of the component:

```
<!-- Dynamic grid generation using ng-template and ng-content. This is generated several times using the *ngFor, for every item in the items array we will have a componentLoader -->

<ng-template componentLoader>
</ng-template>
```

There is a lot more content in these files but for simplicity I will only post this, If you need more code just tell me.

Okay, so my problem is that when I access to `this.contentLoader` the returned value is just undefined, so `this.componentLoader.viewContainerRef` causes an error because componentLoader is undefined.

I've tried adding the exportAs property to the directive's decorator and it is giving exacly the same error.

I've also tried to add the directive in the module declarations without success, and changed the  `<ng-template componentLoader>` to `<ng-template #loader=componentLoader>` which causes a different error ( No directive has 'componentLoader' exportAs or something like this )

PS: In the ´´´this.componentFacotryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component)``` I successfully have each component that has been given to the grid.

> I prefer you not to solve my issue but to point me in the right direction and help me see what am I doing wrong in order to improve myself.

Any help will be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve this issue in a very simple way.

I was trying to do too many things inside the grid component so I removed to code related to the component loader and moved it into a single component, called ComponentLoaderComponent.

Inside the component I've setted up all the logic in the same way than I did in the grid component. So now I have a new ts file like this:

```
import { Component, ComponentFactoryResolver, Input, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ComponentLoaderDirective  } from 'src/app/shared/directives/componentLoader.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'component-loader',
  templateUrl: './component-loader.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component-loader.component.css']
})
export class ComponentLoaderComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() public component: any;
  @ViewChild(ComponentLoaderDirective, { static: true }) componentLoader!: ComponentLoaderDirective;

  constructor(
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadComponent();
  }

  loadComponent():void {
    if (this.component) {
      let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.component);
      let viewContainerRef = this.componentLoader.viewContainerRef;
      viewContainerRef.clear();
      let componentRef  = viewContainerRef.createComponent<any>(componentFactory);
    }
  }
```

And an HTML like this:

```
<ng-template componentLoader>
                
</ng-template>
```

Now from the grid component I only have to call the ComponentLoader for every component I want to add to the grid, so the grid html will look like this:

```
<div     
   *ngIf=" gridItem.components && gridItem.components.length > 0"
   class="component-container"
>
       <component-loader
         *ngFor="let component of gridItem.components"
         [component]="component">

        </component-loader>
</div >
```

Now the components are getting loaded correclty, anyways I still don't know what I was missing in before.